# changes not upadated in eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat

I am writing a simple registration form in html using Eclipse Indigo.But after running one time  on server Apache Tomcat 6.0 ,it is giving perfect output.But later if i am trying to modify any value in html form then it is not updating in resulting browser output

Comment: Are you changing java (e.g. servlet) code or just plain HTML?

Comment: @blackcompe just plain html i am changing ,so we need not to restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Press "Republish" button on the "Servers" view in your Eclipse window.

Comment: does it required  to do explicitly,because previously it is automatically updating the browser output according to the changes in html page

Answer (score 0):

I report a similar fact and its solution: fantasy names for files. Eclipse Neon. I create: Red.html with code for a red button and Green.html with code for a green button. I choose Google browser from Eclipse ide and display correctly both html. Then I destroy, from Eclipse ide, Red.html and rename Green.html to Red.html. I launch the renamed Red.html and I see a red button instead than a green one. I open Google settings, and cancel navigation data from the last hour. Now Red.html displays green button. I've done so, because Internet Explorer, not involved in previous manouvres works right: present Red.html displays green button. I haven't tried the ide way as in the previous answer, as I'm new to Eclipse. I tried the browser side with caution: only 1 hour of navigation.